# Stop off market installation

Tags: android, google-apps-marketplace

Does anyone know how I can test how the user installed the application? For example, I want to ensure they are installing it from the android market or other places I have distributed.

Not that it is a big deal, but I hate seeing my apps show up on other markets that I haven't submitted to.

Tried to do a search, but wasn't able to get a result that was applicable.

Comment: is someone re-uploading them without your consent to other markets?

Comment: Do you know about App licensing from Android? Check it out: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html I think it is something that you want

Answer (score 1):

Check the name of the installer returned by the package manager:

```
context.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName())
```

This method is used to retrieve the package name of the application that installed a package. This identifies which market the package came from. See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String)

Note that null is returned for side-loaded apps (e.g. when you install the app using Android Studio during development).